# How do I pass a Child Directive's Data to a Parent Directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I pass a child attribute directive's scope or attr value to a parent directive?

Given `widget` directive, with `in-viewport` attribute directive, I want to update the attribute `inView` each time the document is scrolled, and pass the updated value to the parent directive `widget`:

`<widget in-viewport></widget>`

In Viewport directive: passed in as an attribute of parent directive "widget"

```
angular.module('app').directive('inViewport', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: false, // ensure scope is same as parents
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        angular.element(document).on('scroll', function() {
          // I've tried binding it to attr and parent scope of "widget" directive

          attr.inView = isElementInViewport(element);
          scope.inView = isElementInViewport(element);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Widget Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('widget', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        inView: '='
      },
      transclude: false,
      templateUrl: 'directives/widgets/widgets.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        console.log('In Viewport: ', scope.inView); // Null
```

Comment: what is the parent directive? what is the child directive?

Comment: Since `in-viewport` is an attribute on `widget`, I thought `widget` would be the parent directive of `in-viewport`

Comment: as confusing as it may sound, these directives are siblings, architecturally speaking.

Comment: but a directive on a controller template is a child? Confused. How can I achieve creating a service for a directive which updates the directive's scope variable / attribute on scroll?

Comment: Question: Using a console.log, can you confirm if this line `scope.inView = isElementInViewport(element);` is getting called on that event handler at all? If it is, and you are not seeing the value change, it could be that you need a `scope.$apply()` inside your `scroll` handler to refresh the model correctly.

Comment: @SylonZero yes it's being called. No need to scope.$apply()

Comment: Sorry, let me make that clearer. There are 2 methods that have helped me solve similar issues: a well-placed $scope.$apply() or, to avoid digest collisions but still ensure a value is updated, wrapping the assignment statement - in your case, `scope.inView = isElementInViewport(element);` - with a `$timeout(<func with your assignment here>, 0)`. In principle, your approach looks fine to me. I think the issue might be the coordination of the DOM scroll event and the Angular digest cycle (a very common problem).

Comment: Ok, I will post a working fiddle explaining the above - should have posted this stuff in an answer anyway instead of comments. My fiddle will use **your** directive names and your code objective and will only fake the `isElementInViewport` function.

Comment: @growler Can you mark the most helpful answer as Accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can expose an API on your parent directive and use isolateScope() to access it.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynotravid/xaanvL49/2/).

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive("widget", function($rootScope){
        return {
        template: "<div>Scroll this page and widget will update. Scroll Y: {{scrollPosY}}</div>",
      scope: {},  // <-- Creating isolate scope on <widget>.  This is REQUIRED.
      controller: ['$scope', function DirContainerController($scope) {
        $scope.scrollPosY = 0;
        // Creating an update function.
        $scope.update = function(position) {
          $scope.scrollPosY = position;
          $scope.$digest();
        };
      }],
    }
});

app.directive("inViewport", function($window, $timeout, $rootScope){
        return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link:function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl){
        // Get the scope.  This can be any directive.
        var parentScope = element.isolateScope();
        angular.element(document).on('scroll', function() {
          // As long as the parent directive implements an 'update()' function this will work.
          parentScope.update($window.scrollY);
          console.log('parentScope: ', parentScope);
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Re "Not sure why you want inView as a 2-way bound parameter but here goes" - What I really want is a reusable method where I can tell if any widget with the attached `inViewport` service will be able to know whether or not it is in viewport view on scroll.

Comment: If that is the case I believe this is the answer.  Have you tried the fiddle?

Comment: Oh I gotchu.  You want a directive that will work for different kinds of widgets. Sorry didn't get it the first time.

Comment: Updating solution with alternative.

Comment: @Growler, I have updated this solution to use a method of grabbing the isolatd scope thereby making is work for any widget as long as it it implements an update() method.  I think this addresses all the concerns you have raised.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can access parent directive variables,

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('widget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<viewport in-view="variable"></viewport> <h1>{{variable}}</h1>',
        link: function(scope, iAttrs) {

            scope.variable = 10;
        }
    }
}).directive('viewport', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
                inView: "=",
            },
        template: '<button ng-click="click()">Directive</button>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                        scope.click = function() {
                scope.inView++;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <widget></widget>
</div>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/p75DS/784/

If you have any question, ask in the comment box

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle using your directive structure:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9591/

Markup is like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="height: 1200px;">
  {{name}}
  <hr>
  <widget in-viewport></widget>
</div>
```

Just scroll the window to trigger the event. Note that the **parent** directive has a watch just to prove that the var gets updated...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('inViewport', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: false, // ensure scope is same as parents
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        angular.element(window).bind('scroll', function() {
          console.log('Called');
          $timeout(function() {
            scope.inView++;
          }, 0);
        });
      }
    };
  });

  myApp.directive('widget', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      transclude: false,
      template: '<p>This is a widget</p>',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.inView = 0;
        console.log('In Viewport: ', scope.inView); // Null

        scope.$watch('inView', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('Updated by the child directive: ', scope.inView);
        });
      }
    }
  });

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Angular Directive Stuff';
}
```